# Multi Domain in Multiple wordpress Installation

Tags: wordpress

I have installed `Bitnami WordPress` in separate folders to create two domains.

```
first site: bitnami/wordpress

second site: bitnami/wordpress2
```

**I am using 2 installations of WordPress**. I want to link the two websites.

In my first site (`wordpress`) ie. the company site, I have menus like `Home Services Products` etc.So I want that if I click on `Products` it should open the second site (`wordpress2`) i.e., the product site.

Is it possible? If Yes, how I can I do that.

Comment: Yes.  Just create two different virtual hosts and then directly link them together

Comment: just put the link of the second domain page in the products menu item, you really have to do nothing else

Comment: Ok it works now ...... by just putting the link of the second domain page in the products menu item.

Comment: Thanx for the help